# Using Genymotion emulator with Ionic framework

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, genymotion

I've downloaded and installed **genymotion** and created and built my ionic application.

When I try to run the genymotion emulator using the following command:

```
ionic run android
```

I get the following response:

> No target specified, deploying to emulator
>   No emulator specified, defaulting to Nexus_5_API_21_x86
>   Waiting for emulator...
>   emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
>   Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
>   CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!

[image]

The emulator is not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 30):

It's because ionic sees Genymotion AVD's as physical devices. So instead of using

```
$ ionic emulate android
```

use (note that you need to have the Genymotion AVD running)

```
$ ionic run android
```

Answer (score 5):

I guess you must have installed "Intel x86 Emulator Accellerator HAXM" (you can find it in Android SDK Manager - Extras) but you haven't installed [Intel® HAXM](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows) in your computer.

It gives you that error cause it is trying to run your Ionic App in the Android Emulator.
It seems you haven't configured any [device](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/developers/user-guide) in **Genymotion** or it is not running.

Another thing to consider after you have configured a device in Genymotion is to check that you're using "Genymotion Android Tools"

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Regarding to the ionic 4, the `ionic run android` is removed, so the replaced command is `ionic cordova run`

Make sure that you have already installed the android Sdk and Gradle on your machine

Answer (score 1):

first run Genymotion. then write the command below to watch list of devices attached:

```
adb devices
```

the result would be something like this:

```
List of devices attached
192.168.56.101:5555 device
```

finally write the command:

```
$ ionic run android
```